# What is the error in this Ada program?

Tags: compiler-errors, ada

What is the error in this Ada2012 program?

```
with Ada.Iterator_Interfaces;

package My is

   type Cursor is private;

   function Has_Element (Position: Cursor) return Boolean;

   package Base_Iterators is new Ada.Iterator_Interfaces(Cursor, Has_Element);

   type Bindings_Iterator is new Base_Iterators.Forward_Iterator with private;

   overriding function First (Object: Bindings_Iterator) return Cursor;

   overriding function Next (Object: Bindings_Iterator; Position: Cursor) return Cursor;

private

   type Iterated_Object is access all Integer;

   type Cursor is new Iterated_Object;

   type Bindings_Iterator is new Base_Iterators.Forward_Iterator with null record;

end My;
```

Attempt to check the syntax and semantics:

```
$ gnatgcc -gnat2012 -c my.ads 
my.ads:23:09: type must be declared abstract or "First" overridden
my.ads:23:09: "First" has been inherited from subprogram at a-iteint.ads:26, instance at line 9
```

As far as I understand `First` is overridden by me. I don't get what the compiler complaints for.

Comment: Out of curiosity; how do you plan on releasing the memory allocated by Cursor objects?

Comment: @egilhh This is a shortened version of the real code. In the real code there were no Integer pointers. There was a pointer to an object.

Comment: it's still an access type, and you'll need to free the memory...

Comment: @egilhh note it is `access all`, and `all` here is because I access to an object which may be hold in a local variable not in a memory pool. So there is not need to deallocate it, as it is goes away when the local variable goes out of scope (this is the most likely use case of my code)

Comment: this design will not work with generalized for loops. There is nowhere in the API there for a user to add an access to a local variable. Besides, burdening the user with an extra stack variable per cursor object seems cumbersome

Comment: @egilhh Sorry, but I know what I do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error comes from `Cursor` being a privately derived access type. Changing it to

```
type Cursor is access all Integer;
```

removes the error, as does changing it to a record type or numeric type.
Moving the full definition of `Iterated_Object` and `Cursor` to the public view also removes the error.

I'm thinking you have stumbled upon a compiler error.

Comment: Thanks for the advice how to change my code. It is a useful advice. But you have not explained the exact version why my code does not work. Please help with this too. I don't understand

Comment: I will report the bug